# Iron.io Workers PHP error Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: php, pdo, iron.io, ironworker

I've got this error when launching a php worker on Iron.io :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /mnt/task/...
```

My PHP script just call the native PDO extension like this :

```
$db = new PDO (...);
```

Anybody know if there's a known problem with the docker image iron/php and the PDO extension ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to [add](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Add_a_Package) [php-pdo package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/main/x86_64/php-pdo) into your docker image.

Example of installing php-pdo package via Dockerfile:

`FROM iron/php
...
RUN apk add php-pdo
...`

Comment: I didn't want to use docker to package my worker. I can't get that iron provide a docker image without pdo pré installed. I tried to use other docker image, but nothing worked. Your advice is the best answer i think. Thank you !

Comment: If you don't want to use docker image you can use iron_worker_ruby_ng gem `https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_ruby_ng` for upload and queue your code via cli. Or you can use iron_worker_php lib `https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_php/blob/master/src/IronWorker.php#L79`  to upload and then queue task via your code. (use php-5.5 stack)